# Why is "Variable not in scope"

Tags: haskell

What's the problem with code.

My Haskell platform is new . And I have tried to adjust the formats for many times. But it didn't work all the time.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

encode :: Int -> String -> String
encode shift msg =
    let ords = map ord msg
    shifted = map (+ shift) ords
    in map chr shifted
```

The result is always like this

```
Prelude> :r
Ok, no modules loaded.
Prelude> :type encode

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: encode
```

When I load my files, it shows

```
Prelude> :l H2-2.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( H2-2.hs, interpreted )

H2-2.hs:56:3: error: parse error on input ‘shifted’
   |
56 |   shifted = map (+ shift) ords
   |   ^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: It seems like you never loaded your program, since it says "no modules loaded". Did you run `ghci` with `ghci myfile.hs`?

Comment: `Prelude> :r Ok, no modules loaded` - that makes it looks like you haven't actually loaded your module. You need to do `:l <module_name>` first (then you don't need `:r` until you've made modifications and want to reload it).

Comment: You can simplify this to `encode shift msg = map (chr. (+ shift) . ord) msg`; in general, `map f (map g xs) == map (f . g) xs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an indentation error in your code. Here it is corrected:

```
encode :: Int -> String -> String
encode shift msg =
    let ords = map ord msg
        shifted = map (+ shift) ords
    in map chr shifted
```

In blocks like `let ... in ...` or `where ...`, `do ...` etc, it's important to not allow the indentation of subsequent lines to fall behind the indentation of the first – this is called the ‘offside rule,’ and it's how Haskell determines what belongs in what block.

Start up GHCi with `ghci H2-2.hs` or write `:l H2-2.hs` to load the file. Once it's loaded, if you want to load some additional changes, only then should you use `:r`.